# Oscilloscope noise and 20 MHz bandwidth limit

Tags: noise, oscilloscope

My GW Instek GDS-1102B oscilloscope is showing some high frequency noise even with the bandwidth limit ON, but I am not sure if this high frequency noise should be present or it should be more attenuated if I activate the bandwidth limit.
The first 2 screenshots are with BW limit off, the last 2 with BW limit on.
I would like to know if this is normal for this digital oscilloscope.

Edit: the screenshots are with the tip of the probe connected to the ground of the probe.The probe is set to 10x and the scope also set to 10x.

[image: BW Limit OFF]

[image: BW Limit OFF]

[image: BW Limit ON]

[image: BW Limit ON]

Comment: Without a very clear picture of how you connect the probe to "ground", and where that "ground" is, there's no point in guessing what you did wrong. Start with the basics. Put a terminator (anywhere between 0 and 100Ohm is fine) onto the scope input and see what you get. If you get a flat-ish line, or at least noise within the specs of the scope, you're good, and your probing/connection technique is off.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica `what you did wrong` - nothing has been done wrong as far as I can see. The numbers look about right to me.

Comment: Troubleshooting *probe* or *oscilloscope*? When you view FFT, does this noise appear flat-line(noisy) or does it show peaks? With probe detached, does noise go away? That ground loop is an antenna - wave it around the scope itself - does noise amplitude change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's pretty much down to thermal noise and your oscilloscope probes.**

> *The probe is set to 10x and the scope also set to 10x.*

You say you have a 10x probe and so this will have a 9 MΩ series resistor within the probe that will naturally produce thermal noise. It's the thermal noise that you are seeing.

[Link to Resistor Thermal noise Calculator](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Thermal-Noise-Calculator.phtml).

- With a BW of 20 MHz and 9 MΩ the thermal noise at 20°C is 1.706 mV
- With a BW of 100 MHz and 9 MΩ the thermal noise at 20°C is 3.816 mV

To convert Gaussian RMS values to approximate p-p values, you can multiply by 6.

[See this website for extra details](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/noise-in-electronics-engineering-distribution-noise-rms-peak-to-peak-value-PSD/).

This means that the p-p levels on your oscilloscope will be about 99.73% representative of the whole true waveform (it's a probability thing) so: -

- With a BW of 20 MHz and 9 MΩ the thermal noise at 20°C is 10.24 mV p-p
- With a BW of 100 MHz and 9 MΩ the thermal noise at 20°C is 22.90 mV p-p

[image]

And this assumes your higher BW setting is 100 MHz. It's not far off 22.90 mV p-p and your scope actually displays the p-p reading as 19.6 mV.

[image]

The above is your reduced BW display of noise. The scope displays numerically 10.4 mV p-p.

**It's not far off being about right.**

Answer (score 1):

Do you have good ground? Usually when I have noise, making sure I have good ground solved problems most of the time.

Comment: The screenshots are with the probe connected to GND, The probe is set to 10x and the scope also set to 10x.

Comment: Probe ground as in the clip lead? Most probes have a metal ring near the tip. Get a piece of thin wire and wrap that around the ring and tip. Also note that noise performance is what you pay money for.

Comment: There are no problems to solve here. This is what you would expect from a x10 oscilloscope probe.